# How do I shoot "snowy beard" portraits in studio?

Tags: portrait, snow

I'm looking for a way to create the frosty beard with snow portrait in studio with controlled lighting. The problem is of course that snow/ice melts. Are there any fake snow/ice that is used in these situations or do I have to make the model rummage around with his face in the freezer just before the shot is taken?

I'd like to create something like [this](https://500px.com/photo/6594554/cold-days-self-portrait-by-philipp-franceschini) (although this one was taken in the mountains).

Answer (score 1):

You can actually buy artificial snow from retailers such as Amazon: [http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B004BG5JYG/ref=as_li_ss_tl?ie=UTF8&tag=fstoppers-20&linkCode=as2&camp=1789&creative=390957&creativeASIN=B004BG5JYG#](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004BG5JYG)

You might also get some good results from cloudy ice. Ice that you find in your freezer etc...

Also have a look at this article here as they use different techniques to create different snow themed images. https://fstoppers.com/studio/bts-video-best-way-create-fake-snow-your-photos-7088